# regex replace iframe/object by youtube video id

Tags: php, regex

I have the html like below. Basically it has three videos some of them embed by iframe tag other object tag. I have the YouTube video id. So I want to replace the iframe/object tag with some text (Video can't be showed here ) by YouTube video id.

MY HTML

```
<p>Video 1</p>
<p><iframe width="604" height="453" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TOsGAxFcYls?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>

<p>Video 2</p>
<p><iframe width="604" height="340" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y-AYC3_DbpY?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>


<p>Video 3</p>

<object width="560" height="315"><param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/-1jKtYuXkrQ?version=3&hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/-1jKtYuXkrQ?version=3&hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

Now, I want to replace the replace the video 1 and 3. I have both video id's.

- video 1 = TOsGAxFcYls
- video 3 = -1jKtYuXkrQ

Now, I want to replace both iframe and object by particular text.

Expected output

```
    <p>Video 1</p>
    <p><strong>Video 1 has been removed video id (TOsGAxFcYls)</strong></p>

    <p>Video 2</p>
    <p><iframe width="604" height="340" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y-AYC3_DbpY?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>


    <p>Video 3</p>

   <strong>Video 3 has been removed video id (-1jKtYuXkrQ)</strong>
```

> Note :  I may add custom replacement text for each replacement of
>   video.

please help me out with regular expression to do the above job!

Comment: This seems like a JavaScript job, unless you are fetching that HTML from a database.

Comment: @Allendar: No I want to do this in php.

Comment: If you know the video id, the regex is quite simple: `<p>.*video_id.*</p>`, for your first video: `<p>.*TOsGAxFcYls.*</p>`

Comment: but how do i know it's wrapped by object or iframe

Comment: You don't even care about that, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, just add the ID's and their replacement texts to the `$video_ids` array.

```
$html= ... // your html here
$video_ids = array
    (
      array("TOsGAxFcYls","First replacement text"),
      array("Y-AYC3_DbpY","Second replacement text")
    );    

foreach ($video_ids as &$video_id) {
    $patt = "/<object(.*)$video_id[0](.*)<\/object>/";
    $html = preg_replace($patt, $video_id[1], $html);
    $patt = "/<iframe.*?src\=".*?'.$video_id[0].'.*.<\/iframe>/i";
    $html = preg_replace($patt, $video_id[1], $html);
}

echo $html; // here are your changed values
```

Comment: Nope, that's the problem. I need may add custom replacement text for each replacement

Comment: Answer updated for your needs. just edit the ID's and the replacement text in the first array, and you are set.

Comment: Your code only replace the video id not the entire iframe or object that contains video id.

Comment: Thanks for try to answer. But your pattern will replace everything inside the p tag. I just want to replace the iframe/object that contains specific video id. actually you can have a look at m.pons answer that pattern works for iframe. I need to do that for object also.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code that I believe has the effect your asking for:

```
<?php
$text = '<iframe width="604" height="340" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y-AYC3_DbpY?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

$matches = array();
$video_id = "Y-AYC3_DbpY";
preg_match('/<iframe.*?src\=".*?'.$video_id.'.*.<\/iframe>/i', $text, $matches);
if(!empty($matches)){
    //replace iframe;
}
else{
    //do something else
}
?>
```

Comment: I edited your pattern that works for iframe. if can help me for object it will be very helpful

Comment: @gowri, check my updated answer below, it works as you specified.

Comment: the preg_match part for object would be: `preg_match('/<object.*?value\=".*?'.$video_id.'.*.<\/object>/i', $text, $matches);`